# Uploading a file to vscode.dev

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, download, upload

Not programming related, more about how to use a programming tool, but I really have no idea where I can ask though. I found myself doing this often enough to justify searching for a solution.

1. I use a cloud instance of VSCode, e.g. https://vscode.dev
2. Is there a way to upload/download a binary file?
3. Meaning, creating a new file through copy and paste won't cut it
4. I did a search on the marketplace, nothing useful
5. VSCode seems to have be a built-in way, under extension's menu,  `Install from VSIX...`, `Show Local` and we can pick a local VSIX that will be uploaded and installed remotely

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**for Upload:**

- Right click on the folder
- Select "Upload..."

[Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5bxE.png)

**for Download:**

- Right click on the file
- Select "Download..."

[Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52EhW.png)

The official document link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/10/20/vscode-dev#_local-development-with-cloud-tools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).